# angular 1.x animation: while using ng-repeat, i want to trigger enter animation after completing leave animation

Tags: angularjs, animation

I am using angular animation lib for showing up animations while displaying an array of person objects using ng-repeat. I am running into problems for below use case.

I have a card-layout which shows 4 cards (i.e, 4 person objects) initially using `limitTo` filter and then paginating one card at a time. On each card i have a delete button and onClick it removes the item from array (which triggers leave animation) and next items move to left to accommodate a new element (triggers an enter animation for new element only). Since `leave` and `enter` animations happening at same time, the card which entered is shown in next row until the the leave animation on another card is completed.

So i want to delay the enter animation until the leave animation is completed. SO is there a way to achieve this ? I have gone through several stack overflows and angular documentation, but no luck.

Comment: I tried using custom event through $emit on $rootScope through javascript animation service, but no use

Comment: Can you set up a small example in Plunker? Would be much easier to help.